# Source for not sleeping above a sefer Torah

Tags: halacha, sefer-torah, sleep, rabbi-yehudah-hechasid

Where can I find the source not to sleep above a sefer Torah, online, in hebrew? I was told it comes from R' Yehudah Hachasid.

Comment: Do you mean "sleep above"?

Comment: @shmosel Yes. Thanks!

Comment: @שלום I didn't see the halacha not to sleep above a sefer Torah there.

Comment: 1. Would seem to be disrespectful to sleep "above" any Sefer let alone a Sefer Torah. 2. Could you clarify for this question what you mean by "above"? If there was a shul in a basement you would be above the Torah just being being in the floor above it. You probably don't mean that but it would improve your question to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam responding to a question regarding the permissibility of living in an apartment above a synagogue wrote ([Pe'er ha-Dor 74](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=23523&st=&pgnum=62)) :

> יכול לדור בבית, אבל המקום אשר מעל ההיכל, אינו יכול לישן שם, ולא להניח
> כלי מלאכתו. אבל בשאר הבית יעשה כרצונו
>
> It is permitted to live in such a house, however the place that is
> immediately above the Hekhal, it is not permitted to sleep there. And
> it is not permitted to leave there everyday objects. However in the
> rest of the home it is permitted to do as one wills.

The [SA (151:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.151.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> יש ליזהר מלהשתמש בעליה שעל גבי ב"ה תשמיש קבוע של גנאי, כגון לשכב שם;
> ושאר תשמישים, יש להסתפק אם מותר להשתמש שם
>
> One should be cautious to not permanently use an attic above a
> synagogue for a degrading purpose, such as to sleep there, and as for
> other usages it is doubtful whether it is there permitted to use.

The [Sefer Hasidim 812](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91) wrote:

> אחד היה משים ספר תורה בחדר התחתון והיה נותן מטתו בחדר העליון כנגדו אמר
> ליה זקן אחד לא יתכן לעשות כן...לשם תשמיש של קדושה מותר אבל שאר דברים
> כגון מטה או כלי של טנופת לא יתכן להיות למעלה כנגדו
>
> Someone once placed a Sefer Torah in a room below and his bed in the
> room immediately above it. An elder/rabbi told him that it is improper
> to do such... for sacred functions it is permitted but for everything
> else, such as a bed or degrading vessels it is improper to place them
> immediately above it